# can not delete files of "Recent" folder using java

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to program a small utility program using java that will delete temp files, recent places etc. When i try to list files of `C:\Users\Username\Recent` to delete them but it is returning `null`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
public class Simpledeleter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder=new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Recent");
        deleteFolder(folder,false);        
    }

    public static void deleteFolder(File folder,boolean flag) {
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();
        if(files!=null) {
            for(File f: files) {
                System.out.println("accessed folder!");
                if(f.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("deleting contents of "+f);
                    deleteFolder(f,true);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("deleting file "+f);
                    f.delete();
                }
            }
        }

        if(files==null){
            System.out.println("returned null!");
        }

        if(flag==true){
            folder.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Am i having permission problems here? Any help on this?

Comment: Yes. You are having a permission issues here.

Comment: Show your code.. ? what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I added the codes, if someone can help, plz do.

Comment: Yeah its permission issue

Comment: there is only one user in my PC, so i am running everything as administrator. So where exactly is this permission issue occurring?is it possible to solve this?

Comment: Please perform `dir /ash C:\Users\hp` and add the results to your question.